# iOS: if-else within a stringwithformat

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, if-statement, stringwithformat

I am an iOS newbie, so please bear with me.

I want to construct a string using stringWithFormat, but I want to put in a part of a string only if a condition is true. How would I achieve something like -

```
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", 
           @"myString1",
           //put myString2 only if (someCondition)]
```

Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most legible way to do this would be to use an explict `if` block.

However, you can also do it inline with the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

```
BOOL condition = YES;
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", @"string1", 
                                                     (condition) ? 
                                                         @"string2" : 
                                                         @""];
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to achieve that is to insert an empty string if the condition is false and use the second string is true like this:

```
myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"myString1",
           (condition) ? @"This is myString2" : @""];
```

Comment: In Obj-C `true` should be `YES`. Also, there's no need to compare against `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *myString = nil;
if (condition1) {
   myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", condition1];
} else {
   myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", condition2];
}
```

Comment: Looks a lot better than the others, but is a lot longer.

Comment: Yeah, this is just for easy to read if else block. The other answers are just as effective, just a little different looking than if/else code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    BOOL test =0;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"myString1", test? @"Mystriong 2":@"Mystring3"];
NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
```